# selecting sorted xml node based on some conditions

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have sample xml like this:

```
User
    name   A
    Id     8

User
    name   B
    Id     5

User
    name   C
    Id     16

User
    name   D
    Id     10
...
```

This is what i expect, if input is

- A only --> output should be A.
- B only --> output should be B.
- A and B only --> output should be B.
- Any users other than A and B --> output should be name of user with lowest id.
- A, B and other users --> user with lowest id except A and B.

I have tried different variants of below template

```
<xsl:template name="getPriorityName">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='User']">
            <xsl:sort select="./*[local-name()='Id']" data-type="number"/>  
            <xsl:variable name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="./*[local-name()='name']"/>
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$name!='A' and $name!='B'">
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>       
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But since i am unable to club name condition with for-each it does not work in case when A and B are there in input

Thanks Jirka :)
I modified the tempalte a little bit and now it looks ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Users">
        <xsl:variable name="UsersCount" select="count(User)" />
        <xsl:variable name="UsersExceptAB" select="User[Name != 'A' and Name !='B']" />
        <xsl:variable name="UsersAB" select="User[Name = 'A' or Name ='B']" />
        <xsl:variable name="UserInABWithMinimumId" select="$UsersAB[not($UsersAB/Id  &lt; ./Id)]" />
        <xsl:variable name="UserExceptABWithMinimumId" select="$UsersExceptAB[not($UsersExceptAB/Id  &lt; ./Id)]" />

        <result>        
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$UsersExceptAB">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$UserExceptABWithMinimumId" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$UsersAB">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$UserInABWithMinimumId" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:comment>Oops, something is wrong.</xsl:comment>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a way i can just assign the name to a variable; let's say; priorityName that i can use later, i have some other logic based on this priorityName in my application. I tried to access name from node, but since what we finally have is a node set(always of size 1 - either UserInABWithMinimumId or UserExceptABWithMinimumId). This is what i tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="priorityName">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$UsersExceptAB">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$UserExceptABWithMinimumId/User/Name" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$UsersAB">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$UserInABWithMinimumId/User/Name" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:comment>Oops, something is wrong.</xsl:comment>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Ken, I added template that i tried for this problem

Comment: Yes, you should be able to store name of user in variable. You are very close, just change xpath in `<xsl:value-of select="$UserExceptABWithMinimumId/User/Name" />` to `<xsl:value-of select="$UserExceptABWithMinimumId/Name" />` (as well as in `<xsl:value-of select="$UserInABWithMinimumId/Name" />`. Hypothetically, there could be also more than one user in your variable so you can also make something like `$UserExceptABWithMinimumId[1]/Name` just to be sure exactly one name is stored in you variable.

Comment: Thanks. I got the name but the variable that i am getting is a node fragment, can i change this to string?

Comment: I think you don't need to do it becaus when you use `xsl:value-of` you get a string. Or you can use `string()` function to convert it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Users">
        <xsl:variable name="UsersCount" select="count(User)" />
        <xsl:variable name="UsersExceptAB" select="User[Name != 'A' and Name !='B']" />
        <xsl:variable name="UsersExceptABWithMinimumId" select="$UsersExceptAB[not($UsersExceptAB/Id  &lt; ./Id)]" />

        <result>        
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- There exists some User with other name than A or B-->
                <xsl:when test="$UsersExceptAB">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$UsersExceptABWithMinimumId" />
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- There exists no User with other than A or B but there is a User with name B -->
                <xsl:when test="User[Name = 'B']">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="User[Name = 'B']" />
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- There is no User with other than A -->
                <xsl:when test="User[Name='A']">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="User[Name = 'A']" />
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- Probably there is no User -->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:comment>Oops, something is wrong.</xsl:comment>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I used this input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Users>
    <User>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Id>8</Id>
    </User>
    <User>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Id>9</Id>
    </User>
    <User>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Id>6</Id>
    </User>
    <User>
        <Name>D</Name>
        <Id>10</Id>
    </User>
        <User>
        <Name>E</Name>
        <Id>11</Id>
    </User>
</Users>
```

(and commented different User for testing purpose) it returned me desired output.